# How to conceptualise Hierarchial m-state time-event model with multiple absortion states;non exclusive states

Tags: time-series, survival, multilevel-analysis, time-varying-covariate

I am designing a clinical study to investigate factors modifying the relationship between toxin exposure and its consequences. Since the original work is sensitive, I share an identical scenario.

Exposure to UV light causes freckles, cataract & bad mood. But, not everyone gets all or even one of them. Some host factors modify the response. Each of these has multiple transitional stages. Say for freckles: Normal(M0)-> redness (M1) -> temporary spot (M2)  -> permanent freckle (M3). M3 being the absorption state. If the exposure to UV changes, the subject may move from M2 -> M1. Also, the same subject may come to the M2 state multiple times. Imagine similar transitional states for cataract & bad mood. If I want to test the hypothesis that a certain gene predisposes to UV related consequences after adjusting for age etc. a multi-state model seems suitable.

Now, my problem is: The states are not mutually exclusive. A subject may have redness of the skin, early cataract & bad mood at the same time. If I make a combination of these states, it will be very high with some states having no transitions at all.

Also, there is a hierarchical structure of data, first, at the subject level, which can be taken care of with subject-specific intercepts. But also, at the outcome level. For example, state M1, M2 and M2 described above belong to 'freckles'; thus, their transition intensities are likely correlated.

How does one conceptualise and execute such a model?